# C++ linked list class

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have a lot of experience in Python and Haskell but am new to C++, so I'm wondering if my code is idiomatic. For one of the first assignments in my class, I wrote a linked list class (the "cities" are nodes in the linked list, the teacher wanted to make things interesting, I guess). Here's the header I had to implement, the functions are described with comments:

```
#ifndef COMMUNICATIONNETWORK_H
#define COMMUNICATIONNETWORK_H
#include <iostream>
struct City{
    std::string cityName;
    std::string message; //Ignore this bit, it's not relevant
    City *next;
    City *previous;

    City(){};

    City(std::string initName, City *initNext, City *initPrevious, std::string initMessage)
    {
        cityName = initName;
        next = initNext;
        previous = initPrevious;
        message = initMessage;
    }

};

class CommunicationNetwork
{
    public:
        CommunicationNetwork();
        ~CommunicationNetwork();
        void addCity(std::string, std::string); //Insert city with given name after city with given name
        void printNetwork(); //Go through and print all city names
        void deleteCity(std::string); //Remove city with given name
        void deleteNetwork(); //Free all memory, name the cities being deleted, replace head with NULL
    protected:
    private:
        City *head;
        City *tail;
};

#endif // COMMUNICATIONNETWORK_H
```

Here's my implementation (the weird output formatting was mandatory):

```
#include "CommunicationNetwork.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

CommunicationNetwork::CommunicationNetwork()
{ head = new City; tail = new City; }

CommunicationNetwork::~CommunicationNetwork()
{ if(head) CommunicationNetwork::deleteNetwork(); }

void CommunicationNetwork::printNetwork()
{
  if(head == NULL)
    {
      cout << "===CURRENT PATH===" << endl;
      cout << "NULL" << endl;
      cout << "==================" << endl;
      return;
    }

  cout << "===CURRENT PATH===" << endl;
  cout << "NULL <- ";
  City* currentCity = head;
  while(currentCity->next != NULL)
    {
      cout << currentCity->cityName << " <-> ";
      currentCity = currentCity->next;
    }
  cout << currentCity->cityName << " -> NULL" << endl;
  cout << "==================" << endl;
}

void CommunicationNetwork::addCity(string prevCity,
                   string newCity)
{
  if(prevCity == "First")
    {
      head->previous = new City(newCity, head, NULL, "");
      head = head->previous;
    }
  else
    {
      City* currentCity = head;
      while(currentCity != NULL)
    {
      if(currentCity->cityName == prevCity)
        {
          currentCity->next = new City(newCity,
                       currentCity->next,
                       currentCity,
                       "");
          currentCity->next->next->previous = currentCity->next;
          break;
        }
      currentCity = currentCity->next;
    }
    }
}

void CommunicationNetwork::deleteCity(string city)
{
  if(head->cityName == city)
    {
      head = head->next;
      delete head->previous;
      head->previous = NULL;
    }
  else if(tail->cityName == city)
    {
      tail = tail->previous;
      delete tail->next;
      tail->next = NULL;
    }
  else
    {
      City* currentCity = head->next;
      while(currentCity->next != NULL)
    {
      if(currentCity->cityName == city)
        {
          currentCity->previous->next = currentCity->next;
          currentCity->next->previous = currentCity->previous;
          delete currentCity;
          break;
        }
      currentCity = currentCity->next;
    }
    }
}

void CommunicationNetwork::deleteNetwork()
{
  if(head == NULL)
      return;

  City* currentCity = head->next;
  while(currentCity != NULL)
    {
      cout << "deleting " << currentCity->previous->cityName << endl;
      delete currentCity->previous;
      currentCity = currentCity->next;
    }
  cout << "deleting " << tail->cityName << endl;
  delete tail;
  head = NULL; tail = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Overall very good.

Only some minor pointers.

## A look at some things to do differently

### Namespaces

- Put your code in your own namespace.
- Include the namespace in the macro guard.

### Only include headers you need.

```
#include <iostream>
```

It does not look like you need any stream functionality in the header file. Even if you did you should use the stream forward headers `#include <iosfwd>`in header file and use `#include <iostream>` includes in the source file.

### Ownership semantics.

Ownership is about showing who is responsible for deleting a dynamic object. The trouble with pointers is that there is no ownership associated with them so using them is dangerous.

```
City *next;
City *previous;
```

Here I believe you are using it correctly. But I would make that clear by at least commenting it. That will make your intention be obvious.

B.Stroustroup and H.Sutter are trying to introduce the [concept of `Views`](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#gslview-views) which are non owning pointers.

```
GSL::view
```

But this is still just at the idea state but will (probably) become part of how modern C++ will be written in the future.

### Always Initialize members

```
City(){}; // Note: that ';' is not required.
```

Here you default initialize your members. Default initialization of pointers does nothing and leaves then in an indeterminate state.

### Use Initializer list to initialize members

If you don't initialize members in the initializer list then they will be initialized using the default constructor before the body of the constructor is entered.

SO in this constructor.

```
City(std::string initName, City *initNext, City *initPrevious, std::string initMessage)
{
    cityName = initName;
    next = initNext;
    previous = initPrevious;
    message = initMessage;
}
```

You first initialize the `cityName` and `message` using the default constructor. Then you use the assignment operator to copy the parameters into the members. This can be in-effecient. So prefer to use the initializer list so that members are constructed in the correct state as much as possible.

```
City(std::string initName, City *initNext, City *initPrevious, std::string initMessage)
    : cityName(initName)
    , message(initMessage)
    , next(initNext)
    , previous(initPrevious)
{}
```

### Rule of Three

This is a simple rule. That states if you define the copy constructor assignment operator or destructor then you probably need to define all three.

Consider this code:

```
CommunicationNetwork    networkOne;
CommunicationNetwork    networkTwo(networkOne);  // Copy using the copy constructor.
```

You did not define the copy constructor. But the compiler generates a default copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor and default constructor. So the above code will compile. When pointers are involved the default version does not always work the way you want (hence the above rule). Please look up details in other questions but the short story this will lead to double delete as these object go out of scope.

### Pass by const reference rather than value

```
void addCity(std::string, std::string);
```

Here you are making a copy of the parameters (both strings) each time you call this method. Strings are expensive to copy.

### Style: * and & are part of the type

In C++ (different from C) the type qualifiers are traditionally placed next to the type not the variable.

```
City    obj;            // obj  is a "City"
City*   loop = nullptr; // loop is a "City pointer"
City&   next = obj;     // next is a "City reference"
```

### Use operator<< to print the object.

Its OK to have your own print function (`printNetwork()`). Just also add an output operator.

But you should be able to specialize it by passing an output stream (even if the default is `std::cout`). Also printing the object should not modify the object so the print method should be `const`.

```
class CommunicationNetwork
{
    public:
        void printNetwork(std::ostream& out = std::cout) const;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, CommunicationNetwork const& data)
        {
            data.printNetwork(out);
            return out;
        }
};
```

Don't use this.

```
using namespace std;
```

Please read. [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/14065).

### Your List design.

Using a sentinel (which seems to be what you are doing) is a very good idea for a doubly linked list because it actually reduces the complexity of writing the list code (because you don't have to test for NULL (there is always a sentinel)). But You are also testing for NULL so this leads me to suspect that you are doing it wrong.

There are several examples on code review how to do it correctly.

### Prefer `nullptr`

Since C++11 the use of `NULL` has been deprecated in favor of using `nullptr`. It provides a type safe way of defining a null pointer.

### Prefer "\n" over std::endl

They both add a `\n` character to the stream. But `std::endl` will also flush the stream. This is usually not what you want. Humans are very bad a deciding when t flush the stream and the default behaviour for flushing is very close to optimal. Let the code work out the optimal times when to flush. Also if it needs to flush (ie before reading input from `std::cin`) this is also done automatically.

### Don't use Magic Values

```
void CommunicationNetwork::addCity(string prevCity,
                   string newCity)
```

Having `prevCity` have a special magic value of `"First"` is going to get you in trouble. I would use something else. Probably a specific function.

### Prefer `for(;;)` over `while()`

Prefer the for loop over the while loop. Especially when you have a move next that can be put into the for condition rather than at the end of a statement block that may be a long way from the test condition.

## Code Review

I would simplify some of the methods in `CommunicationNetwork`.

```
// Assuming correct Sentinal.
// Head and tail are the same element (the list is circular).
// The head element is not a member that holds data.
CommunicationNetwork::CommunicationNetwork()
    : head(new City)
{
    // The head is the sentinel. It is not part of the data.
    // The list id circular.
    // Because the list is circular, The head is the tail.

    head->next = head->prev = &head;
}
void CommunicationNetwork::~CommunicationNetwork()
{
    deleteNetwork();
    delete head;
}
void CommunicationNetwork::addCity(string const& prevCity, string const& newCity)
{
    City*  prevCity = find(prevCity);
    if (prevCity != nullptr) {
        addCityAfter(prevCity, newCity);
    }
}
void CommunicationNetwork::addCityAtFront(string const& newCity)
{
    addCityAfter(head, newCity);
}
void CommunicationNetwork::addCityAfter(City* prev, std::string const& city)
{
    City*  newValue  = newCity(city, prev->next, prev, "");
    prev->next->prev = newValue;
    prev->next       = newValue;
}
void CommunicationNetwork::deleteCity(string city)
{
    City*  city = find(prevCity);
    if (city != nullptr) {

        city->prev->next = city->next;
        city->next->prev = city->prev;
        delete city;
    }
}
void CommunicationNetwork::deleteNetwork()
{
    City* next;
    for(City* loop = head->next; loop != head; loop = next) {

         next = loop->next;
         delete loop;
    }
    // Because this is a public function we do need to leave the object
    // in a valid state with the sentinel still in place.
    head->next = head->prev = &head;
}
void CommunicationNetwork::find(string const& city)
{
    for(City* loop = head->next; loop != head; loop = loop->next) {
        if (loop->cityName == city) {
            return loop;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Good review.  I'd additionally suggest that `printNetwork` should return a `std::ostream&` instead of `void`.  Most of the other `void` functions should be re-examined as well to see if there might be something more useful to return.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of good points:

1. Good use of header guards
2. Avoiding use of `using namespace std` in the
   header is good.

The use of `new` and `delete` is discouraged in modern C++, but in this case, since it is for a class project, it is probably okay.  Normally you wouldn't be implementing linked lists yourself.  It does mean you have to be extra careful about memory management though.

You haven't defined or deleted a copy constructor or assignment operator, so you could easily have memory issues.  In your case you would probably just want them to be deleted.

```
CommunicationNetwork(const CommunicationNetwork &) = delete;
void operator=(const CommunicationNetwork &) = delete;
```

Your `City` class looks like it is intended to only be used with the `CommunicationNetwork`.  You might consider making it be a nested class:

```
class CommunicationNetwork {
   .
   .
   .
   private:
       struct City;
};

struct CommunicationNetwork::City {
   .
   .
   .
};
```

Members should be initialized with a constructor initializer list when possible:

```
City(
    std::string initName,
    City *initNext,
    City *initPrevious,
    std::string initMessage
)
: cityName(initName),
  message(initMessage),
  previous(initPrevious),
  next(initNext)
{
}
```

It's a good idea to initialize members that don't have a default value, especially pointers:

```
 City()
 : next(nullptr),
   previous(nullptr)
 {
 };
```

As a general rule, large objects (using more than a few words of memory) should be passed by const reference:

```
void addCity(const std::string &, const std::string &);
```

Prefer using '\n' instead of endl:

```
cout << "===CURRENT PATH===\n";

cout << "deleting " << currentCity->previous->cityName << '\n';
```

There's nothing technically wrong with `endl`, but every time you use it, it flushes the output, which is often an unnecessary performance hit.

Comment: "The use of new and delete is discouraged in modern C++" — what? But there's no garbage collector!

Comment: Why not just pass large objects as pointers instead of const references? Is a const reference just a pointer you can't change?

Comment: @reneg: Standard containers and smart pointers are preferred to using new and delete.

Comment: @RenéG: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/106614/951890 for more info on smart pointers.

Comment: @RenéG: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7058373/951890 for more info on why to prefer references.

Comment: @RenéG: The use of `new` and `delete` is discouraged in general because memory is managed by other techniques: `Containers` or `Smart Pointers`. Now if you are building classes that cover these techniques; then using new/delete is resonable (but most containers and smart pointers are already well covered by the standard or boost).